# Nginx try_files with name from query

Tags: nginx

'm trying to find way how to serve cached files with nginx.

I have stored search results to json file in shared memory.
Next time when user tries to look up the same search, it supposed to be served by nginx by try_files directive.

Here is the request string:

```
/api/ajax-ticker-search?search=SBER
```

Here is what I have in nginx:

```
location /api/ajax-ticker-search/ {

                try_files /dev/shm/searchResults/$arg_search.json @apisearch;
        }
```

I do have file named `SBER.json` in `/dev/shm/searchResults` but nginx is not serving it, always falling back to `@apisarch` location.

What's wrong with try_files and how can make it work and serve stored json file?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've managed this to work, but still don't understand how.

Here is working config:

```
location /api/ajax-ticker-search {
                root /dev/shm/search;
                try_files /$arg_search @apisearch;
        }
```

What I did:

- moved files from `searchResults` folder to `search` folder (no camel case folders?);

  - put `root` directive before `try_files` so filename in try_files directive is now just `/$arg_search` instead of `/dev/shm/search/$arg_search`. (Have to set root?)
  - removed `.json` extension (Just in case)

I have no idea which of theses actually helped, but now it works and I can cache search results from PHP directly to file that then is being read by nginx.